# BufferedReader's readLine() does not work through konsole (Kubuntu 12.10)

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

  String msg;
  BufferedReader userIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.println("please type something now:");
  msg = userIn.readLine();
  System.out.println(msg);  

  userIn.close();
}
```

Works perfectly in eclipse but when I run through konsole msg is not printed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the unbuffered `System.err` instead of the buffered `System.out`

Answer (score 3):

It is OS-dependent. In your case `System.out.println` is using a buffered output. Your program ends before `System.out.println` flushes the message to the standard output, so you don't see anything.

Try calling `System.out.flush()` to force it.

Related questions:

- [When/why to call System.out.flush() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166328/when-why-to-call-system-out-flush-in-java)
- [System.out.println not functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302060/system-out-println-not-functioning)
- [Java: What's the reason behind System.out.println() being that slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950026/java-whats-the-reason-behind-system-out-println-being-that-slow)
- [Java: System.out.println and System.err.println out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help, I should mention the program doesn't terminate (again only in konsole, in eclipse it is fine)